# Test all entries from test data records list

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

I'm currently switching from Python Unittests to pytest, which makes my tests more clear.

But there is one thing which is not clear to me.
In my unittests I iterate through a (for example) list or a response JSON.

```
def test_result_list_xyz():
    api = SomeApi()   
    for entry in api.get_result_as_list()
        self.asserEqual('xyz', entry.xyz, msg='There is a fish in it..')
```

That is just an example, in some other cases I have predefined test data stored in lists. Which will be iterated in a test method and tested.

Example:

```
    {'foo': 'bar'},
    {'foo2': 'bar2'}
]
INVALID_TEST_DATA = [
    {'foo': ['this should not work..']},
    {'foo2': None }
]
```

The downside of this is, that on the first assert, the entire test stops and the rest of the data will not be tested.

How to solve that in pytest without the downside of stop on the first error?

Is there a way to run a test on every iteration, so that at the end I have tested all entries from the list? (If 3 entries are in the input list, 3 tests should be executed.)

And what is the best way to test a bunch of data with pytest in general?

Answer (score 0):

How about using an approach like the following

```
INVALID_TEST_DATA = [
    {'foo': ['this should not work..']},
    {'foo2': None }
]


def test_result_list_xyz():
    api = SomeApi()   
    for entry in api.get_result_as_list():
        for key, value in entry:
            self.asserEqual(INVALID_TEST_DATA[key], entry[key], msg='There is a fish in it..')
```

This will make sure that whatever list our function is returning it fetches the elements from the list and iterates via the key and value of each individual dicts.